# Xcode 4.4 turned my iOS project into a Mac OS X project! How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode4.4, build-settings

I've opened an iOS project - with Xcode 4.4.1 - that I hadn't opened for 2 months (ie with Xcode 4.3). First, Xcode was crashing constantly right after displaying the project navigator saying something like **"Failed to associate working tree"**.

I tried to fix it by removing xcuserdata files and the project.xcworkspace directory as well.

Now, Xcode opens without crashing but in the scheme view, it is shown as a Mac OS X project whereas both the project and the target are correctly set to a "Latest iOS" base SDK.

How can I fix that without having to recreate a project and copy all my source files?

EDIT: i'm using Git with a GitHub remote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20228910/1355118
This answer solved my issue, hope this helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make a new scheme for ios by clicking on the current scheme then "new scheme"

Answer (score 1):

Roll back using version control.  If you post which version control system you are using, somebody will be able to give you the specific command to use.

Comment: i'm using Git but i have nothing to rollback. I haven't modified anything and my git status is clean :(

Comment: You say in your question you have modified things - have you checked anything in recently?

Comment: The files I removed are in my .gitignore. No other recent modification.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with all my Xcode projects. Every iOS project got turned into an OS X project without me changing any settings. A reinstallation of Xcode fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just set your Root SDK to iOS in your target's Build Settings

```
SDKROOT = iphoneos
```

Comment: It's clearly mentioned it's already the case in the question.